# Select all values in p:selectManyCheckbox

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I´m dealing with one problem, I have a `p:selectManyCheckbox` with a `Map` with 27 values, that I want to select them. But I want to have one `selectManyCheckbox` to select all values, but I don´t know how to do this.

I found solution in `javaScript` to use with `JSF` but I don´t know how to use with `PrimeFaces` or can use also with a `Bean`.

My code is like this

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="ufs" value="#{lojaBean.pojo.ufsInss}" layout="grid" columns="4" styleClass="columnLeft">
    <f:selectItems value="#{lojaBean.helper.estados}"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Todas"/>
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

So how can I do this?

Comment: Just add a selectItem with value="all" - and then bind that as a value in your backend to save all values.

Comment: You can do it with **ajax**

Comment: I´ve tried to do it using binding with `events` but didn´t worked as I want, can you show me a example?

Comment: Can you show me a example using ´ajax´?